# Making banner background image transition in timed slideshow

Tags: html, css, transition, banner

I have been strugling with making my background image change to other images over time. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The code in the css is:

```
#banner {
background-attachment: scroll, fixed;
background-color: #494d53;
background-image: url("images/overlay.png"), 
url("../img/full_res/4.jpg");
background-position: top left, center center;
background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
background-size: auto, cover;
color: #d1d2d4;
padding: 15em 0;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
}
#banner:after {
-moz-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
background: #3d4045;
content: '';
height: 100%;
left: 0;
opacity: 0.675;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1;
}
#banner :last-child {
margin-bottom: 0;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  IMAGES of code are not acceptable.

Comment: You want a background image carousel ?

Comment: Yes thats what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet to make background image slider

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
}

.slideshow {
  list-style: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slideshow li span {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: transparent;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: none;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
  -moz-animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: imageAnimation 24s linear infinite 0s;
}

.slideshow li h3 {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 150px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 4.0625em;
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 24s linear 1 0s;
  -moz-animation: titleAnimation 24s linear 1 0s;
  animation: titleAnimation 24s linear 1 0s;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .slideshow li h3 {
    bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 8.125em;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .slideshow li h3 {
    font-size: 10.9375em;
  }
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(1) span {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/203277/summer-slide.jpg);
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/203277/fall-slide.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(3) span {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/203277/winter-slide.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}

.slideshow li:nth-child(4) span {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/203277/spring-slide.jpg);
  -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
  -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
  animation-delay: 18s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  12.5% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  37.5% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  12.5% {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  37.5% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  12.5% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  37.5% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  12.5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  37.5% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  12.5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  37.5% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes titleAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  12.5% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  37.5% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.no-cssanimations .slideshow li span {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class='slideshow'>
  <li>
    <h3>The Seasons</h3>

    <span>Summer</span>
  </li>

  <li>
    <span>Fall</span>
  </li>
  <li>

    <span>Winter</span>
  </li>
  <li>

    <span>Spring</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please do tick the answer if this solves your problem

Comment: Perfect glad to help out

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for image slider or image carousal. 
You can do this in bootstrap easily
here is the link for bootstrap 
[bootstrap_carousel link](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp)
here is the link for css and jquery 
[css_slideshow](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp)
**I hope this will help you.**